# Simple CMS software to manage files

Tags: php, file-management, cms

I've been loking around recently for an easy way to manage the files on my web server. I came accross [OneFileCMS](http://onefilecms.com/) which is fine but lacks some features. I'm looking for another piece of software (PHP of course) that could act as a replacement to onefile.

All I need to do is:

- Manage my files (delete, rename, edit)
- Create new files/folders

Anything come to mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many many options for what you describe. Not sure I'd call that a CMS, but whatever.

If you do a [search for "php file manager"](http://www.google.com/search?&q=php%20file%20manager&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8), you'll see what I mean. Here are some examples you could check out:

- [File Thingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/) (I actually use this one)
- [fileNice](http://filenice.com/demo/) (another one I use)
- [PHPfileNavigator2](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/index.php?opc=1&lg=ing)
- [eXtplorer](http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/)
- [FILEMANAGER](http://www.gerd-tentler.de/tools/filemanager/)

Anyway, explore those, find one you like.

Have fun!

Comment: Ahh perfect! I was under the impression these were called CMS', so my searches were all crap. Thanks again. Will accept in 3 minutes.

Comment: No worries, glad to help. Took me a fair while to figure out what to call these too. I had similar challenges this way. If you want to get in to something very industrial strength in this space, you may want to look at something like Alfresco. But you said "easy way to manage", not sure Alfesco is inherently easy to use as it's so feature rich.